# Plot Graph In web application

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing a web application using Spring. I need to plot graphs and display them to the user. The values are stored in a database. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decide where do you want to create the charts. You have two options:

1. Creating the chart on the server and send them to the client as image or pdf.
2. Sending raw data to the client and let them render the charts via html, flash or javascript

Each way has its own advantages and limitations - you have to decide for your specific use case.

If you render the charts on server side you are limited regarding interactivity but you clients don't need much performance to render the charts. Here you have to think about caching to protect your server performance.

On the client side you have to deal with diffent browsers and must think about the client render performance.

If 2. is ok for you, I would recommend using javascript - so your users don't need to install any plugins like flash and you have a lot of possibilites to create nice charts.

There are some nice frameworks to create charts using javascript, for example:

- [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)
- [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)
- [JS Charts](http://www.jscharts.com/)
- ...

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) with Spring MVC before. Normally whenever I have needed to display chart, I have always displayed tabular data along side the chart as well. So, I just take jQuery, parse the html table for data and pass it to google Chart API. You may want to look at the Google Chart pages for examples. It is quite nice.

Answer (score 0):

As @aiolos said, you can generate your chart image in the client or in the Server. I haven't work with JavaScript enabled charts, but when I have to generate charts the server-side way i'll go with [Cewolf](http://cewolf.sourceforge.net/new/index.html). It's a Java Library based of JFreeChart that has some useful tags to embed charts in JSP pages.

I tested it in Spring Applications and works like a charm.