# Auto generating graph for website

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I'm using java spring for backend of my website. I need to add some auto generating graphs to it. But I'm not sure for what I should look for. Should I use a `Javascript` library or can I do it in `java` as a backend function? This is my first time using this functionality.

P.S. 
I have to deal with a often updating database to fetch data for those graphs.

Comment: What do you mean auto generating graphs? Are you referring to graph or pie charts for analytics?

Comment: In descriptive manner I need some think like weight with respect to age of a child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer, I would suggest to go with option 2 and use a javascript library like highcharts.

[Plot Graph In web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533605/plot-graph-in-web-application)